# Each value in the node of a chain is calculated from the previous value plus the sum of the digits of the previous value

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, nodes

I'm pretty new to this sort of thing and am trying to find how to work out a function which takes two integer values, the starting value and how many nodes in total should be in the chain. Each value in the chain of a node is calculated from the previous value plus the sum of the digits of the previous value. For example:

```
(409, 5)
```

would generate a chain of

```
409
422
430
437
451
```

My code right now:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, init_data):
        self.data = init_data
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next = new_next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

def generate_chain(start, n):
    node = Node(start)
    current = start
    string_of_nodes = str(start)
    list_of_nodes = []
    print(current)
    for digit in string_of_nodes:
        list_of_nodes.append(int(digit))
    for i in range(n-1):
        node.set_next(sum (int(a) for a in list_of_nodes) + int(current))
        current += (node.get_data())
        print(current)
```

Generates an output of:

```
409
818
1227
1636
2045
2454
```

I'm wondering if someone can help me find my error and guide me the right way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative implementation that uses the `Node` class can be the following:

```
def generate_chain(start, n):
    head = node = Node(start)
    for _ in range(n):
        sum_of_digits = 0
        v = node.get_data()
        while v > 0:
            sum_of_digits += v % 10
            v //= 10

        node.set_next(Node(node.get_data() + sum_of_digits))
        node = node.get_next()

    node = head
    while node:
        print(node.get_data())
        node = node.get_next()
```

This code creates a chain of nodes and then prints. The issue in the original code seems to be that the chain was not constructed correctly since `set_next` was called with `int` instead of `Node`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of where I went wrong. Also what does the line `head = node = Node(start)` differ from going `head = Node(start)`; `node = Node(start)` in two lines. I haven't seen that before.

Comment: I also don't know what the line `while node:` is supposed to do.

Comment: Regarding `head = node = Node(start)` vs. `node = Node(start)` and `head = Node(start)`, the difference is that `head` and `node` will point at two different object int the latter. Yet, it can be writtern as `head = Node(start)` and `node = head`.
Regarding the `while v > 0`, it's an alternative way to sum the digits. Yet, I think @Tristan way of summing the digits is more elegant.
Regarding the `while node`, it is supposed to print the node values one by one, until we reach the last one. Then the value of `node` will be `None` and the loop will end.

Answer (score 1):

This could be implemented nicely as a generator I suppose:

```
def chain(steps, value):
    for i in range(steps):
        yield value
        value+=sum([int(i) for i in str(value)])

x = chain(5, 409)
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

If you want to use the Node class, you can use this function:

```
def generate_chain(start, n):
    node = Node(start)
    for k in range(n):
        yield node.get_data()
        node.set_next(node.get_data() + sum(int(i) for i in str(node)))
        node.set_data(node.get_next())
        value = node.get_data()

I = generate_chain(409, 5)
for i in I:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Short solution using `s.append(x)` function and arithmetic modulo operator `%`:

```
def generate_chain(num, total):
    chain = [num]  # setting the initial value
    total -= 1
    while total:
        chain.append(chain[-1] + chain[-1] // 100 + chain[-1] // 10 % 10 + chain[-1] % 10)
        total -= 1
    return chain

print(generate_chain(409, 5))
```

The output:

```
[409, 422, 430, 437, 451]
```